# Access functions within functions in python

Tags: python

Given a function within a function, how do I call the inner function from an external function?

ex.

```py
def a():
    print 'a'
    def b():
        print 'b'
        def c():
            print 'c'

def d():
    # how would I now call a, b and c from here?
    def e():
        # how would I call a, b and c from here as well?
```

Yes I know it's horrible code structure and should not be done - but how do you do it?

Edit: Any way to do this using decorators?

Comment: You can do it by using `class` instead of `def`. What on earth can your use case be?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, it's not quite impossible, but certainly not something you should do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot.  `b` and `c` are local variables inside `a` and do not exist except while `a` is executing.

(Since these are constants, you can technically access them via `a.__code__.co_consts`, but this is not a real solution even if you're okay with horrible code structure.  You would have to execute the function with `exec` and you can't pass arguments to it.)

Comment: And, this is indeed one of the techniques that are used to create absolute *private* attributes in Python.

Comment: @behnam Can you give an example of where absolute private attributes is used in a python program? I'm curious as to why it's necessary, and the actual implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, since those functions are created when the outer function is called, and are destroyed when the outer function exits. You would need to put a reference to the inner function somewhere persistent if you wanted to access them from elsewhere.

Comment: You could, for example, return these references from the outer function.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because no one should get karma for something so perverse, but the obvious place to stash the references is in the function itself.. adding `b.c = c` and `a.b = b` after the function declarations would enable `a.b.c()`.. (shudder)

Answer (score 1):

With this structure, you can only call `a()` in the two places you indicated. `b()` is only defined while `a()` runs, and `c()` is only defined while `b()` runs. `a()` can be called from anywhere since it defined globally.

For example:

```
def a():
    print 'a'
    def b():
        print 'b'
        def c():
            print 'c'

def d():
    # how would I now call a, b and c from here?
    a()
    def e():
        a()
        # how would I call a, b and c from here as well?

d()
```

results in

```
a
```

(Similarly, `e()` is only defined when `d()` is running. `d()`, like `a()`, is defined globally.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your outer function so it will return your inner function